# Python: MySQLdb working great on Linux, not Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, mysql-python

I have a problem with an application I am writing.
Using a file dialog a user picks a file whose values are added to a database, or at least, that's the idea.
Using the mysqldb module I have made all the usual connections at the beginning of the application:

```
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, passwd, database)
    cursor = db.cursor()
```

And then run a piece of code like this:

```
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO info (key1, code, note) VALUES ('testkey1', 'testcode1', 'testnote1;")
     db.commit()
```

The funny thing is that if I run this on Linux (Ubuntu 13.10) it works perfect without errors or issues.
Yet when I run this on Windows (tested on XP and 7), it doesn't commit at all. And I don't get an error to signal there was a problem.
It's only when I check the database that I discover nothing happened.

Does anyone know why I might be having this compatibility issue?

Just to add: The database on Windows is an EXACT copy of the one on Linux.

Comment: what is your python version ?

Comment: Are you sure Mysql-python is correctly installed in your windows station? It's a tricky install with windows..

Comment: Python version is 2.7 for both Linux and Windows. I had to trawl through Google to get the installer for MySQLdb and found it in MySQL-python package found here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Comment: http://www.codegood.com/archives/129 check this , this will work for you i think :)

Comment: Thank you Dibyendu, but I appear to have a more recent version of that package with version 1.2.5

Comment: Ok , i am using that version which i provided you `1.2.3` , worked perfect for me. So i recommended you. i have not tried with `1.2.5` let me check. can you check once with the version I provided  uninstalling the `1.2.5`

Comment: it worked for me with ease for `1.2.5` no issue with software, chk connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I just tried it, but it resulted in the same fail. it's very unusual

Answer (score 0):

It is now solved, it was such a silly mistake, but in case there are any Linux users that NEVER use Windows and do run into this issue, here is the solution.

First ensure that Xampp is installed on the Windows machine.
Ensure the ports are open and MySQL and Apache are installed through the Xampp application.
After this, open PhpMyAdmin and make sure that the permissions of user of the database server match those entered in the python application.
After this, the application will run exactly like on Linux.

I thought installing MySQL along with MySQL Workbench was the right move, but it turns out it uses the Apache's version.

Thanks to everyone who helped.